# OpenGL without a graphics card

Tags: opengl

Is is possible to do Open GL development and run programs on a computer with out a graphics card? (e.g. my netbook running Ubuntu)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

***Update*** This was many years ago, the link is not available anymore, and there are probably newer, better, builds now.

Yes, you can use [MESA](http://www.mesa3d.org/).

For your convenience, I've compiled it in both 32- and 64bit at:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9496269/mesa.zip

Simply put them where your executable file is located.

Comment: linux system. say that again with out a .exe xD

Comment: @Narcolapser Ask your question again with the word linux in it ;)

Comment: I was aiming for generic but here, how about this.

Comment: @Viktor Sehr The link is dead. Please upload the file again if you still have it. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer, I recommend a newer build as this answer is six years old :)

Comment: I don't know for Ubuntu, but for RedHat (and derivatives) mesa packages are available in the standard distro as of today.

Comment: https://github.com/pal1000/mesa-dist-win, https://fdossena.com/?p=mesa/index.frag

Comment: @ViktorSehr and for Windows® ?

Answer (score 10):

Sure.  Many software only implementations of OpenGL exist.  Check out the Mesa project at http://www.mesa3d.org/ for one of the most popular.  There are parts of the shading language not fully supported, and it tends to lag the standard a bit in general, but that is the case of all software API emulators.  Its still very full featured and can be used in production code for many common uses.

Comment: and for Windows® ?

Comment: @user2284570 What do you mean by windows ? For example, desktop / laptop always has some sort of Nvidia/Intel GPU

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow no, and things like the R2308WFTZSR or Intel Quark is a recent example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenGL on many integrated GPUs, mostly AMD chips like the Ryzen 3 3200G, which has a GPU that is the same as a GTX 1050 for around £100.

Comment: Some computers like mine don’t have any graphics outputs by design which means not even an integrated ɢᴘᴜ.

Comment: hello user22284570 what kind of mother board do you have as most modern one support integrated graphics like am4 and some intel cpu with the lga socket have a varitey to choose from

Comment: Simple, I’m having a R2308WFTZSR computer (well it has graphic output but no drawing graphic computation capabilities much like the first ibm pc).